# split, rearrange and join string in dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe by reading a csv file.

```
INPUT:
def convert_potentials(potential_data):
      data = pd.read_csv(potential_data, sep=';', skiprows = 1,
                         names=["Half reaction", "Electrode potential/V"])
            
      print(data)

convert_potentials(oxidation_potentials.txt)
```

The output:

```
                   Half reaction           Electrode potential/V
0                  Na -> Na+ + e-                    2.71
1               Co2+ -> Co3+ + e-                   -1.81
2                 H2 -> 2H+ + 2e-                   -0.00
```

I want to change the value of 'Electrode Potential' to -(Electrode Potential) and I want to rearrange the equation in 'Half reaction' in reverse order.

The expected output:

```
                   Half reaction           Electrode potential/V
0                  Na+ + e- -> Na                    -2.71
1               Co3+ + e- -> Co2+                    1.81
2                 2H+ + 2e- -> H2                    0.00
```

To achieve this, I used the following solutions:

```
    data['Electrode potential/V'] = -data['Electrode potential/V']
    
    def rearrange(x):
        return "->".join(data['Half reaction'].str.split(pat = "->")[::-1])
    
    data['Half reaction'] = data['Half reaction'].apply(rearrange)

    return data
```

I get the expected value for Electrode Potential, but an error for half reaction:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

I know that I need to split the string, but I don't know how to rearrange it back as I want in the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding your rearrange function should be like this:

```
def rearrange(x):
        return " -> ".join(x.split("->")[::-1])
```

because, you are using it to apply and not directly manipulating data.

Answer (score 0):

The function apply, applies the function on every row in the column. So you don't have to specify the data you want to use inside the function (data['Half reaction']). Insted the data is passed though the x variable from your function definition.

**Insted use x to access the data:**

```
def rearrange(x):
    return x.split(' ')[::-1]

data['Half reaction'].apply(rearrange)
```